# Android Studio wizard for Fragments and other templates

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-support-library

Every time I create a new Fragment in my Android Studio for the project, it creates **android.support.v4.app.Fragment**, which is not what I want. Also, it alsways triggers a gradle update. How to set default Fragment to **android.app.Fragment** when creating new one with wizard and get rid of gradle updates?

Comment: "How to set default Fragment to android.app.Fragment when creating new one with wizard" -- most likely, you would need to write your own template for the wizard. Last I checked, that's not documented or supported, though it can be done. In theory, you could edit the existing template, but your changes will get clobbered when the IDE is updated, most likely.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use the `Fragment` from the support library? I would always recommend doing that even if you don't care about backwards compatibility. There is no reason not to use them. The `Fragments` from the support library do more than just ensuring backwards compatibility.

Comment: And of course you could always just not use the wizard. I never even touch the wizards, its much faster to just create the classes and layout files yourself from scratch.

Comment: Is a Gradle update a problem? Would you care to explain why else you don't want to use the support version?

Comment: I don't need Support Fragment because I don't need to go that far back. Also, I think there is code in that library that I will never use so why using a tool that has something that I don't need? I'm still investigating this issue (SupportFragment vs Fragment) but I don't think it gets me any added value.

Comment: As far as I can tell, using the wizard will always add the compatibility library dependency to the app and then make use of it to write the scaffolding code.  I don't think there is a way to tell it to stop.  Just write the code yourself.

Comment: @CommonsWare - What do you mean by "get clobbered"? I actually thought about same solution but I have to understand how to do it properly.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson - Writing code by hand every time when I create a new Fragment is not very smart. It's only a good solution when you don't have another choice. And it's just as far as it can be from any engineering best practices. Every repetitive task should be automated if it makes the process faster and without errors.

Comment: @shadox: Google updates their own templates. They are not expecting developers to be changing those templates. Hence, the next time Google ships an update to the fragment template that you modified, your changes may get overwritten. That's why I suggest that you have a separate template, perhaps cloned from theirs, that you modify. Particularly if you choose an uncommon name (e.g., get `shadox` in the filename somewhere), Google isn't going to ship their own replacement for it. Again, though, this is all undocumented, so Google could do anything, including change the entire template system.

Comment: @shadox: "Every repetitive task should be automated if it makes the process faster and without errors" -- only if it will result in a net time savings. Otherwise, it's yak shaving.

Comment: @CommonsWare - exactly, that's why I want to stop gradle sync and putting wrong tempaltes in place.

Comment: @shadox If you don't want to write the code every time, make your own template, and use Studio's "Save File As Template" option to make your own template.

Comment: I'll try all these suggestions and I'll be back with feedback

Comment: You can use AndroidX dependency that `android.app.Fragment` was deprecated inside it.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers!

As CommonsWare mentioned in comments changing the templates may not last longer as Android Studio updates may overwrite them. So you may create your own custom file templates as described in following article.

https://riggaroo.co.za/custom-file-templates-android-studio/

Here you may have to create two file templates

- One for Fragment class
- Another for fragment layout file

---

Another way to go about changing the fragment template is to **backup the original files of that you are going modify and modify the existing templates and backup the modified templates in order to restore the modifications after an Android Studio update.**

It's important to backup original files before modification, because when updating android studio in future, it will notify you about files being modified, so the update could not be completed. So you have to restore the original version of the modified files, before updating the android studio.

If you need to change Fragment template (Blank fragment template), navigates to

```
[android-studio-ndredirectory]/plugins/android/lib/templates/other/BlankFragment/root/src/app_package
```

and modify the source file of your choice. (`BlankFragment.kt.ftl` or `BlankFragment.java.ftl`), in order to modify the **source** file template.

Navigate to

```
[android-studio directory]/plugins/android/lib/templates/other/BlankFragment/root/res/layout
```

and modify the `fragment_blank.xml.ftl`, in order to modify the **layout** file template.

After doing your modifications, you may backup the `BlankFragment` directory, so you can restore your changes, after the Android Studio update.