# Why is Android Studio auto-importing android.app.Fragment instead of androidx.fragment.app.Fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-support-library, androidx

My Android Studio Project (migrated to AndroidX) (TheInstrumentals) automatically imports android.app.Fragment whenever I make a Fragment from Android Studio's Fragment Wizard. How can I make it auto-import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment?

I've tried making a new Blank Fragment from another project (ViewPagerTest) (also migrated to AndroidX) and it imports androidx.fragment.app.Fragment automatically instead of the deprecated android.app.Fragment.

My other project (Udacity Project) (not in AndroidX) automatically imports android.support.v4.app.Fragment when the same thing was done.

com.mydomain.theinstrumentals.BlankFragment.java:

```
package com.mydomain.theinstrumentals;

import ...
import android.app.Fragment; //imported automatically
import ...

public class BlankFragment extends Fragment /*Fragment was strikedthrough */ {...}
```

com.mydomain.viewpagertest.BlankFragment.java:

```
package com.mydomain.viewpagertest;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment; //imported automatically

import ...

public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {...}
```

com.example.android.miwok.NumbersFragment:

```
package com.example.android.miwok.NumbersFragment;

import ...
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; //imported automatically
import ...

public class NumbersFragment extends Fragment {...}
```

Comment: I have read a related article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797829/why-android-studio-doesnt-auto-import-the-correct-package-android-support-v4-ap but it's old and doesn't explain why the other project automatically imports the right Fragment (androidx.fragment.app.Fragment).

Comment: Clean build your project and just check your Import Settings once!

Comment: Novo, I tried cleaning and rebuilding my project but it didn't do anything. Also, what do you mean by checking my Import Settings once?

Answer (score 0):

My answer to the linked post isn't old - the imports are still alphabetical and the options to auto import are modifiable in the settings

Short answer - AndroidX is extra, and later on the classpath, not on the core API, therefore it's listed later in the import menu

Plus, the Fragment wizard uses internal template files for creating new classes for all components, and can't assume that you have AndroidX as part of your code. If it did, then it would have to insert those plugins into the Gradle build, for example

Comment: My gradle build explicitly implements the AndroidX components and no, it's not just alphabetical, because my other project implements the AndroidX version instead of the android.app version. Both of the projects were migrated to AndroidX the same way (by clicking the migrate to AndroidX in refactor).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying that the import menu shows AndroidX Fragments first? It doesn't matter if your project is using the classes

Comment: What you're asking for seems like this first comment here - the internal IDE templates can't be easily modified reliably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964204/android-studio-wizard-for-fragments-and-other-templates#comment59583362_35964204

Comment: No. I don't know what was listed first. It's just, the other project (ViewPagerTest) is automatically importing androidx.fragment even if android.app is the one that should be listed first due to the fact that you said that it's alphabetical.

Comment: Also, it's not that. Yes, I'm asking how to change the default Fragment to import, but I'm also wondering why the other project auto-imports the right one (androidx.fragment.app.Fragment) while the other auto-imports android.app.Fragment

Comment: Automatically how? New Java files are just empty. If you create a file from the wizard, it's not that class, right? And templates can be built from existing files https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/save-file-as-template-dialog.html

Comment: And in my experience, if a class name collides, there's no auto importing - even mentioned in the docs there is a dialog https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html

Comment: No. Not just blank Java files. When I created a Fragment by going to File>New>Fragment>BlankFragment, the imported Fragment is the wrong one (android.app.Fragment) on the first project while the right one was imported on the latter project (androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188137/discussion-between-hamu-xd-and-cricket-007).